# Проблема при компиляции с Makefile

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, makefile

Есть простенькая команда на питоне, пытаюсь её скомпилировать через команду make и используя Makefile, но выдаёт следующую ошибку:

```
gcc -o Test main.py

/usr/bin/ld:main.py: file format not recognized; treating as linker script

/usr/bin/ld:main.py:1: syntax error

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:4: Test] Ошибка 1
```

Работаю на Ubuntu

В чём может быть проблема?
И какие пути решения есть?

Код:

```py
import sys

sys.stdout.write('hi')
```

Содержание Makefile:

```
Test: main.py
    
      gcc -o Test main.py
```

Comment: Gcc это компилятор си. А у Вас код на питоне. Его нельзя таким образом скомпилировать. Что делать? Питоновский код запускать интерпретатором питоном.

Comment: То есть я правильно понимаю что вместо gcc я должен использовать CP, ну и после внести некоторые правки?

Comment: если код на питоне, то просто берите и запускайте его питоном - python main.py. Если очень сильно-сильно нужно - можно конечно это через make запускать, но вряд ли это нужно делать

Comment: Нет, мне нужно именно через make это сделать, я поменял gcc на cp и поменял -o на -a, и после выполнения появился текстовый документ Test, я достиг правильного результата? Просто когда я пытаюсь проверить работоспособность через "./Test" пишет отказано в доступе? исправив это командой "chmob 777 Test" появляются новые ошибки
./Test: строка 1: import: команда не найдена
./Test: строка 3: синтаксическая ошибка рядом с неожиданным маркером «'hi'»
./Test: строка 3: `sys.stdout.write('hi')'

Comment: Ну логично. Это как будто Вы китайско-немецким словарем переводите с испанского на суахили.